# Series and Sequences Question about homeloans

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, geometric-series

[The question and the working I got for the question are shown in the picture.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijpqy.jpg)

Sorry for my messing working.
I am not sure if this is the way to solve this question and how to check whether it is the right answer. 
Thank you any help and guidance is appreciated. 
HamDog

Comment: You have the right idea but you've made a mistake.  $n$ is measured in months, not years, so $n \neq 30$.  It's considered a courtesy to put your question (using MathJax) and your efforts to solve it (which are more than adequate in my book to demonstrate a good faith effort to work the problem on your own) directly into the question rather than in a link.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you for your help, I will remember to use MathJax now thank you.